# How to sort by results of a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method on my User.rb model in my Rails app that returns a reputation score based on a user's various contributions to the site.

```
   def total_votes
    answerkarma = AnswerVote.joins(:answer).where(answers: {user_id: self.id}).sum('value') 
    contributionkarma = Contribution.where(user_id: self.id).sum('value')

    answerkarma + contributionkarma
   end
```

In the index action of my imaginary artists controller, sometimes I retrieve all artists, and sometimes I retrieve only those filtered by location

```
 def index


     if params[:province_id]
     province = params[:province_id]
     province = province.to_i
     @artistsbyprovince = User.artists_by_province(province)

     else

     @artists = User.where(:onionpealer => true)

     end


   end
```

If I'm filtering by location, the User model calls this scope method

```
   scope :artists_by_province, lambda {|province|
      joins(:contact).
      where( contacts: {province_id: province},
             users: {onionpealer: true})
      }
```

What I'd like to do, however, is, in both cases (whether filtering by location or retrieving all users) is to sort the retrieval of the artists by the results of total_votes method, so that artists with the highest number of points appear at the top.

Can you suggest how I might do that. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If do not pay attention on wrong query architecture, sorting can be done by ruby `array#sort_by`

```
@artistsbyprovince = User.artists_by_province(province).sort_by{ |u| -u.total_votes }
```

Comment: Thanks, but one problem. It's returning users with the most votes at the bottom. They should be at the top.  Also, what do you mean when you say "If do not pay attention on wrong query architecture" I don't understand.

Comment: Update my answer to change sort direction

Comment: I mean if you have many users, say 10000++, extracting them from db and ordering by votes in ruby will be very long and memory consuming operation. The right way is caching votes in database and ordering in sql query.